# Dynamic 365 : SQL query to retrieve all picklist values and text

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

On my Dynamics 365 i have a long picklist attribute in my Account(contact) entity. Attribute name called **new_nationality** (196 values).

How do i write the SQL query to retrieve those all values from CRM Sql Db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through the CRM Db and i found the table. find my query which i used which i used to retrieve given below.

```
SELECT  Value as 'Label', AttributeValue as 'Value'
FROM StringMap s
JOIN EntityLogicalView e on s.ObjectTypeCode = e.ObjectTypeCode 
WHERE  s.LangId = 1033 and AttributeName = 'new_nationality' and LogicalName = 'account'
order by AttributeValue
```

[image]